# AS3 URLRequest, add a string to a variable and go to that new URL?

Tags: actionscript-3, url, variables, urlrequest

This is driving me crazy right now!

var url gets defined longer up.

```
url = url + ".jpg";
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
```

That's doesn't work for some reason... the ".jpg" doesnt get added. BUT, if I try to do this:

```
url = ".jpg" + url;
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
```

It works, but I don't want the .jpg to be at the begining of the url ofcourse...

Comment: Have you tried tracing `url` and seeing what comes up? It may do it properly but with an overlooked hitch.

Comment: The code: url = ".jpg" + url; var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
completly no sense. As puggsoy say check the value of the url. Maybe you need to use URLVariables and/or UrlHeaders

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Yes, the variable url is correct. In the first one with url + ".jpg" it just doesn't add .jpg to the end of it.

Comment: Becouse no matter what is the value of variable "url" the string ".jpg" is not a valud url addres. Check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#URLRequest()

Comment: `trace(url,url+".jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Try
    url += ".jpg";
Or
    url = String(url)+".jpg";

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking all day for the same problem. Came across this thread on my way through. Found the solution.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html

So I will share to help speed you up.

This definitely works.

var currImage:int = 1;

var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("folder=../images/&currImage=1&file=.png");

var url = urlVariables.folder + urlVariables.currImage + urlVariables.file;

```
 //changes image..
url = urlVariables.folder + 2 + urlVariables.file;
```

or

```
url = urlVariables.folder + currImage + urlVariables.file;
```

You can just remove the second urlVariable ( &currImage=1).
I've just shown how it all works.

From here you can manipulate the number variable to load other images.